# integration of multidimensional data (matlab)

Tags: performance, matlab, numerical-integration

I have a (somewhat complicated expression) in three dimensions, x,y,z.  I'm interested in the cumulative integral over one of them.  My best solution thus far is to create a 3D grid, evaluate the expression at every point, then integrate over the third dimension with cumtrapz.  This is just a scaled down example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
%integration
xvec = linspace(-pi,pi,40);
yvec = linspace(-pi,pi,40);
zvec = 1:160;
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(xvec,yvec,zvec);
f       = @(x,y,z) sin(x).*cos(y).*exp(z/80).*cos((x-z/20));
output  = cumtrapz(f(x,y,z),3);

%(plotting)
for j = 1:length(output(1,1,:));

    surf(output(:,:,j));
    zlim([-120,120]);
    shading interp
    pause(.05);
    drawnow;
end
```

Given the sizes of vectors (x,y~100, z~5000), is this a computationally sensible way to do this?

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for an improvement/speed up you might want to post this to CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

if this is the function form you want to integrate over,@(x,y,z) `sin(x).*cos(y).*exp(z/80).*cos((x-z/20))`, `x`,`y`,`z` can be separately integrated and the integral can be analytically solved using complex number by replacing `sin(x)=(exp(ix)-exp(ix))/2i`, and `cos(x)=(exp(ix)+exp(ix))/2`, which will greatly reduce the time cost of your calculation

Comment: aha, I've made my example too simple.  The actual expression is non separable, but fine point.